# Query taking long time to execute

Tags: mysql

I have the following query, I am using the betwen operators to fetch the records who have the age between the specific numbers, but the query is taking a hell lot of time to display me the results, its benn more than 5 mins it is still running

```
SELECT
  *,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM users
   WHERE
     1=1 OR
     LOWER(age) BETWEEN 18 AND 20 OR
     LOWER(age) BETWEEN 20 AND 25 OR
     LOWER(age) BETWEEN 25 AND 30 OR
     LOWER(age) BETWEEN 30 AND 35
  ) AS totalcount
FROM users, states, countries, user_types, media
WHERE
  users.id_user_type = user_types.id AND
  users.id_state = states.id AND
  users.id_country = countries.id AND
  media.id_user = users.id AND
  media.profile_photo = 1 AND
  users.id_user_type = 3 OR
  LOWER(age) BETWEEN 18 AND 20 OR
  LOWER(age) BETWEEN 20 AND 25 OR
  LOWER(age) BETWEEN 25 AND 30 OR
  LOWER(age) BETWEEN 30 AND 35
ORDER BY users.id
```

The troubling Part is:

```
LOWER(age) BETWEEN 18 AND 20 OR
LOWER(age) BETWEEN 20 AND 25 OR
LOWER(age) BETWEEN 25 AND 30 OR
LOWER(age) BETWEEN 30 AND 35
```

Comment: What are you trying to retrieve with this query?

Comment: How have you come to the conclusion that it's that part of the query that is the troubling part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using the `or` clause you have (it does not make sense). Your query is probably doing a lot of CROSS JOIN operations and that's why it's taking too long (your resultset is HUGE).

```
 select *,
        (
            select count(*) 
              from users 
             where 1=1 
                or lower(age) between 18 and 20 
                or lower(age) between 20 and 25 
                or lower(age) between 25 and 30 
                or lower(age) between 30 and 35
        ) as totalcount 
   from users, states, countries, user_types, media 
  where users.id_user_type = user_types.id 
    and users.id_state = states.id 
    and users.id_country = countries.id 
    and media.id_user = users.id 
    and media.profile_photo = 1 
    and users.id_user_type = 3 
  order by users.id
```

Also, it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish with this query.

Answering these question might help us help you:

1. What's the `age` column type
2. What exactly are you expecting from your inner query

Comment: What about `WHERE 1=1` and all the other `BETWEEN` statements? Why use LOWER(age). Is age a string? Why compare it to numbers then? I think you should address those issues as well, when saying "it does not make sense".

Answer (score 0):

Your `or` statements are parsed incorrectly.  You need parentheses:

```
FROM users, states, countries, user_types, media
WHERE (users.id_user_type = user_types.id AND
       users.id_state = states.id AND
       users.id_country = countries.id AND
       media.id_user = users.id AND
       media.profile_photo = 1 AND
       (users.id_user_type = 3 OR
        LOWER(age) BETWEEN 18 AND 20 OR
        LOWER(age) BETWEEN 20 AND 25 OR
        LOWER(age) BETWEEN 25 AND 30 OR
        LOWER(age) BETWEEN 30 AND 35
       )
```

As written, your query has to do a full cartesian product among the five tables and then do some weird filtering.

This would be basically a non-issue if you used proper `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  NEVER use commas in the `from` clause.

In addition, the query doesn't seem to make sense.  Why would you store `age` as a string (as suggested by the use of `lower()`?  Then, why would you compare these to integers?  Why would you split consecutive ranges into four different comparisons, instead of just saying `age between 18 and 35`?